# Why i'm getting this error when i build Storybook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, storybook

I just upgraded Storybook from V6.5.9 to V7.1.0 in an exciting Next.js project. Everything works fine, but when I try to build my storybook, it throws the following error:

```
ERR! => Failed to build the preview
ERR! 1620.ba7f2216.iframe.bundle.js from Terser plugin
ERR! Unexpected token: punc ({) [webpack://../node_modules/@storybook/components/dist/index.mjs:195,5420][1620.ba7f2216.iframe.bundle.js:5264,5512]
ERR!     at js_error (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:550:11)
ERR!     at croak (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1274:9)
ERR!     at token_error (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1282:9)
ERR!     at unexpected (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1288:9)
ERR!     at as_property_name (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:3076:20)
ERR!     at concise_method_or_getset (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2729:20)
ERR!     at class_ (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2685:22)
ERR!     at expr_atom (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2514:23)
ERR!     at maybe_unary (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:3310:19)
ERR!     at expr_ops (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:3361:24)
ERR! 1620.98ef3ea2.iframe.bundle.js from Terser plugin
ERR! Unexpected token: punc ({) [1620.98ef3ea2.iframe.bundle.js:5264,5512]
ERR!     at js_error (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:550:11)
ERR!     at croak (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1274:9)
ERR!     at token_error (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1282:9)
ERR!     at unexpected (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1288:9)
ERR!     at as_property_name (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:3076:20)
ERR!     at concise_method_or_getset (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2729:20)
ERR!     at class_ (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2685:22)
ERR!     at expr_atom (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2514:23)
ERR!     at maybe_unary (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:3310:19)
ERR!     at expr_ops (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:3361:24)
ERR! Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
ERR! Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
ERR! Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
ERR! Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
ERR! Error: => Webpack failed, learn more with --debug-webpack
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:7618
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
ERR!     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
ERR!     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
ERR!     at Cache.shutdown (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:150:23)
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1229:15
ERR!     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
ERR!     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
ERR!     at Compiler.close (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1222:23)
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:7570
ERR!  Error: => Webpack failed, learn more with --debug-webpack
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:7618
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
ERR!     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
ERR!     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
ERR!     at Cache.shutdown (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:150:23)
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1229:15
ERR!     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
ERR!     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
ERR!     at Compiler.close (/Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1222:23)
ERR!     at /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:7570
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/local/Cellar/node@16/16.20.0/bin/node
Arguments: /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.19/libexec/lib/cli.js storybook:build
Directory: /Users/mac/Documents/Next/vactory_next/apps/starter
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
```

From what I can see, it's related to Terser and Webpack.
I tried to google the error, but nothing helped, unfortunately. Any idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having same error - digged that it is happening because of https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/1093 - not sure why don't everybody is getting this error. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

support for static modules for terser [was added in august 2022](https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/1093)
I've forced the terser version to latest now and it builds without this error now.

package.json

```
  "overrides": {
    "terser": "5.19.2"
  }
```